# How to show foreign key in queryset django

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have 1 question.
These are my django models.(This is just example)

```
 class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.Charfield()


 class CommunityBoard(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contents = models.TextField()
```

I send data(nsdictionary format) to server using post

```
 { pk = 1 }
```

in views.py

```
 def detailCommuBoard(request):
     returnValues = {}
     returnValues.update(csrf(request))
     pk = request.POST['pk'];
     detailContents = CommunityBoard.objects.filter(pk=pk)
     returnValues = serializers.serialize('json', detailContents)

     return HttpResponse(returnValues)
```

then, I got serialized data in iphone.(json format)

```
 {
    fields =         {

        contents = "\Uc5ed\Uc2dc \Ud30c\Uc774\Uc36c";
        title = "\Ud30c\Uc774\Uc36c \Ud504\Ub85c\Uadf8\Ub798\Ubc0d";           
        user = 1;

    };        
    pk = 11;
}
```

I want to show User model's username when make queryset, not user model's pk.

please Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change the Queryset to include that information.

```
detailContents = CommunityBoard.objects.filter(pk=pk).values_list('contents', 'title', 'user__username')
returnValues = serializers.serialize('json', detailContents)
```

Comment: Thank's your advice. But using .values_list's output is tuple.
Can't serialize to json.
-> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: detailContents = CommunityBoard.objects.filter(pk=pk).values_list('contents', 'title', 'user__username')
This is <class 'django.db.models.query.ValuesListQuerySet'>

Comment: Thank's you for your feedback. I thought serializar works on iterables, my fault. Probably it would work if you use values, instead of values_list, but I think Rohan solution it's more pythonist than mine anyway, so...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [natural keys during serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys).

So you can try this:

```
returnValues = serializers.serialize('json', detailContents, 
                                    use_natual_keys=True)
```

Comment: Thank's your comment. I'll try it. :D